# Происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Почему у Лисы в народных сказках часто встречается отчество Патрикеевна? Что-то не очень по-русски звучит, если задуматься, больше на английский похоже.

Answer (score 7):

Патрикей — имя старинное, и означало оно “патриций” - “аристократ “. Лет около семисот назад жил-был новгородский князь по имени Патрикей Наримунович, сын Нариманта Туровского, внук знаменитого литовского владыки Гедиминаса. В 1383 году Патрикей стал наместником Новгорода. Князь этот так прославился своей изворотливостью, хитростью, что имя Патрикей с тех пор стало равносильным «хитрецу». А так как лиса издавна считалась в народе самым хитрым зверем 
( разбойница-лиса - хитрая: любит курочек, любит уточек, свернет шею гусю жирному ), то и получила отчество — Патрикеевна.

- [Почему народ прозвал лису Патрикеевной? | shkolazhizni.ru](http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-17728/)
- [Wiki-статья учащихся "Лиса Патрикеевна" | orenwiki.ru](http://orenwiki.ru/index.php?title=Wiki-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F_%22%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%22)

Answer (score 0):

Патрикей, к тому же, имя родом из латинского. 
И в европейских странах ему соответствует, к примеру, имя Патрик. Патрисия - женский вариант имени.